# What should we do with questions about bugs in programs that are fixed by developers?

Tags: discussion, questions

If there's a question like this:

[known_hosts module reports changed when nothing has changed](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/16448/known-hosts-module-reports-changed-when-nothing-has-changed)

Where the OP submitted a bugfix to the developers, which was accepted and fixed - or even in cases where a bugfix is found by answerers and eventually committed - what should happen with these questions?

I don't think it makes a ton of sense to leave them in any state.  Should we close the questions? Flag them and lock them?  Any suggestions?

I don't think we should leave them alone, especially if the community bot is likely to promote them to the main page.